# Add new value in Action for Catalog Price Rule Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog-price-rules, product-prices, customize, custom-discount

I need to add new value in action dropdown So I have copied the related file in the local code pool.

**app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Promo/Catalog/Edit/Tab/Actions.php**

```
$fieldset->addField('sub_simple_action', 'select', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('catalogrule')->__('Apply'),
            'name'      => 'sub_simple_action',
            'options'   => array(
                'by_percent'    => Mage::helper('catalogrule')->__('By Percentage of the Original Price'),
                'by_fixed'      => Mage::helper('catalogrule')->__('By Fixed Amount'),
                'to_percent'    => Mage::helper('catalogrule')->__('To Percentage of the Original Price'),
                'to_fixed'      => Mage::helper('catalogrule')->__('To Fixed Amount'),
                'for_ship'  => Mage::helper('catalogrule')->__('For Shipping'),
            ),
        ));

$fieldset->addField('simple_action', 'select', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('catalogrule')->__('Apply'),
            'name'      => 'simple_action',
            'options'   => array(
                'by_percent'    => Mage::helper('catalogrule')->__('By Percentage of the Original Price'),
                'by_fixed'      => Mage::helper('catalogrule')->__('By Fixed Amount'),
                'to_percent'    => Mage::helper('catalogrule')->__('To Percentage of the Original Price'),
                'to_fixed'      => Mage::helper('catalogrule')->__('To Fixed Amount'),
                'for_ship'  => Mage::helper('catalogrule')->__('For Shipping'),
            ),
        ));
```

**app/code/local/Mage/CatalogRule/Helper/Data.php**

```
public function calcPriceRule($actionOperator, $ruleAmount, $price)
    {
        $priceRule = 0;
        switch ($actionOperator) {
            case 'to_fixed':
                $priceRule = min($ruleAmount, $price);
                break;
            case 'to_percent':
                $priceRule = $price * $ruleAmount / 100;
                break;
            case 'by_fixed':
                $priceRule = max(0, $price - $ruleAmount);
                break;
            case 'by_percent':
                $priceRule = $price * (1 - $ruleAmount / 100);
                break;
            case 'for_ship': //custom added
                $priceRule = $price * (1 - $ruleAmount / 100);
                break;
        }

        return $priceRule;

    }
```

**app/code/local/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Rule.php**
When I have checked in this file and print log it misbehaves.

```
     public function calcProductPriceRule(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product, $price)
        {
            $priceRules = null;
            $productId  = $product->getId();
            $storeId    = $product->getStoreId();
            $websiteId  = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getWebsiteId();
            if ($product->hasCustomerGroupId()) {
                $customerGroupId = $product->getCustomerGroupId();
            } else {
                $customerGroupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
            }
            $dateTs     = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()->getTimestamp();
            $cacheKey   = date('Y-m-d', $dateTs) . "|$websiteId|$customerGroupId|$productId|$price";

            if (!array_key_exists($cacheKey, self::$_priceRulesData)) {
                $rulesData = $this->_getResource()->getRulesFromProduct($dateTs, $websiteId, $customerGroupId, $productId);
                if ($rulesData) {
                    foreach ($rulesData as $ruleData) {
                        if ($product->getParentId()) {
                            if (!empty($ruleData['sub_simple_action']) ) {
                                $priceRules = Mage::helper('catalogrule')->calcPriceRule(
                                    $ruleData['sub_simple_action'],
                                    $ruleData['sub_discount_amount'],
                                    $priceRules ? $priceRules : $price
                                );
                            } else {
                                $priceRules = ($priceRules ? $priceRules : $price);
                            }
                            if ($ruleData['action_stop']) {
                                break;
                            }
                        } else {
                            //this is true for my product, As I am checking with a simple products.
                            $priceRules = Mage::helper('catalogrule')->calcPriceRule(
                                $ruleData['action_operator'],
                                $ruleData['action_amount'],
                                $priceRules ? $priceRules : $price
                            );
                            //print log here
                            if ($ruleData['action_stop']) {
                                break;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    return self::$_priceRulesData[$cacheKey] = $priceRules;
                } else {
                    self::$_priceRulesData[$cacheKey] = null;
                }
            } else {
                return self::$_priceRulesData[$cacheKey];
            }
            return null;
        }
```

The problem is, My product has price 28500, and when I set 1 in the discount amount that is in %, It prints in a custom log file.

```
(
    [rule_product_id] => 691948
    [rule_id] => 18
    [from_time] => 1581292800
    [to_time] => 1581811199
    [customer_group_id] => 1
    [product_id] => 7257
    [action_operator] => for_ship
    [action_amount] => 1.0000
    [action_stop] => 0
    [sort_order] => 0
    [website_id] => 1
    [sub_simple_action] => 
    [sub_discount_amount] => 0.0000
)

priceRules: 23982.75 (one more rule is applied that is for 15% + this 1%, So total 16% discount)
Price: 28500.0000
```

But Nothing is in tables When I get **Product's FinalPrice its return 0.00**. Why It behaves like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved it by placing the file **app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Action/Index/Refresh.php** to **app/code/local/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Action/Index/Refresh.php**

and do the needful changes to **_calculatePrice** function.